# What does it mean to "pass" an interface to an RxJS Store within angle braces?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

Using NgRx and typescript, I keep seeing this syntax in class constructors:

```
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store'
class MyClass {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.count$ = store.pipe(select('users'));
  }
}
```

What is this angle bracket syntax doing? `Store<AppState>`

Comment: It means `private store` is a Store of AppStates. The brackets are a common indicator of sub-type in many languages.

Answer (score 2):

That is an example of a [Generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). Probably the simplest example of a generic is arrays. You can have an array **of** something, such as an array of numbers, or an array of strings. Using the generics syntax (arrays do have an alternative syntax you can use), this would look like:

```
const myNumberArray: Array<number> = [1, 2];
const myStringArray: Array<string> = ['one', 'two'];
```

Store is also a generic. You can have a store **of** something, in this case it's a store of AppState.

Comment: So it is asserting the shape of my `store` to the `Store` class?

Comment: It is being specific about what type of Store it expects. It wants a Store of AppState, not a Store of any other thing.

Comment: Is that agreement with how I stated it, or a correction..?

Comment: Depends what you meant by "asserting". Would you consider it an assertion if it said `private store: number[]`? If yes, then i'm agreeing with you. But "type assertion" has another meaning in typescript, in which typescript can't figure out the type is on its own, and so you want to insist to typescript that it treat the unknown variable as the type that you assert that it is. That is not happening here, so if that's what you meant, then i'm correcting you.

Comment: I meant it like, “it is _communicating_ the shape of my `store` to the `Store` class”

Comment: Sorry if i seem like i'm nitpicking; it's just that the way you've asked your question has a number of implications which i don't know if they're intentional or not. Suppose I defined a `const arr: Array<number>;` or a `const arr: number[];` (those are the same thing, just different syntax). Would you say i'm "communicating the shape of my `arr` to the `Array` class"? The answer to that question is the same as the answer to your question.

Comment: The “To array class” seems weird, but I’m not sure how to say it. The communicating data shape (ie interface) seems correct based on what I’m seeing